# Is there any case of table rewrite on add nullable column?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

On the one hand the documentation states clearly that

> When a column is added with ADD COLUMN and a non-volatile DEFAULT is
> specified, the default is evaluated at the time of the statement and
> the result stored in the table's metadata. That value will be used for
> the column for all existing rows. If no DEFAULT is specified, NULL is
> used. In neither case is a rewrite of the table required.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-altertable.html

On the other hand I've heard that because of tuple headers structure in some cases a table might be rewritten.

The documentation states that there are three fields responsible for null values storage behavior

> The null bitmap is only present if the HEAP_HASNULL bit is set in
> t_infomask. If it is present it begins just after the fixed header and
> occupies enough bytes to have one bit per data column (that is, the
> number of bits that equals the attribute count in t_infomask2). In
> this list of bits, a 1 bit indicates not-null, a 0 bit is a null. When
> the bitmap is not present, all columns are assumed not-null.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/storage-page-layout.html

I used this information and `pageinspect` extension to see what is going on with tuple headers when nullable columns are added or deleted. In all cases when I add or delete nullable column I see that existed tuples never change their headers.

So, I cannot find any evidence to the statement that a table might be rewritten. Fields `t_infomask, t_infomask2, t_bits` never change their values.

Am I miss something? Can I say that adding nullable columns to high-volume tables is absolutely safe in terms of disk activity (excluding the fact of exclusive locking)?

Comment: It is hard to comment meaningfully on what unnamed sources might have told you.  Do you know what version they were talking about?

Comment: No, I have no idea about exact version. I agree, that it looks like rumors. That is why I decided to ask a community.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior has changed in PostgreSQL v11. Before that, adding a column with a non-NULL default will rewrite the table.

The point is that from v11 on, the tuple and its header don't have to be modified, adding such a column is just a metadata change. You won't see that with `pageinspect`. NULL values are never stored in the tuple, there is just the NULL bitmap, which is present if one of the table columns is nullable.

Comment: I'm interested in nullable columns only. On the contrary, `pageinspect` alows to see tuple headers as well as its data. Look here https://pgpedia.info/p/pageinspect.html for example.